# curl: Is it possible to create more collections with MKCOL?

Tags: curl, webdav

I try to create a collections with MKCOL curl-command and I get an error: 409 Conflict. I read in specification, that it's only possible to make one collection in the command.
My command looks like following:

```
curl --fail --user ${WEBDAV_USER}:${WEBDAV_PW} -X MKCOL ${WEBDAV_URL}/xxx/yyy/zzz
```

What are the possibilities for solve this problem? Is the only way to create this collections: xxx yyy zzz in the loop?
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's how you need to do it (see http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc4918.html#METHOD_MKCOL)